# Angular 10 downloads compiled assets twice

Tags: javascript, angular, compilation

I have an Angular 10 project where the compiled asset files are downloading twice. As you can see from the attached image, `runtime-es2015.js`, `polyfills-es2015.js` and `main-es2015.js` all download twice. [image: Duplicate downloads in network tab]

Upon inspecting the contents of these files there is suspicious code that looks to be prompting the script to download itself again. I am struggling to find out why this is included in the compiled code:

```
var a,f=document.createElement("script");f.charset="utf-8",f.timeout=120,c.nc&&f.setAttribute("nonce",c.nc),f.src=function(e){return c.p+""+({0:"common"}[e]||e)+"-es2015."+ .....
```

All other answers I have found suggest that this is expected behaviour due to Angular's differential loading, however I am convinced otherwise. The duplicate files have the exact same content whereas if this was Angular's differential loading I would expect the file contents to be different, and also for one to be named `-es5` instead of `-es2015`. We already handle differential loading in code like this:

```
<script type="module" type="text/javascript" src="angular/runtime-es2015.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>
<script type="module" type="text/javascript" src="angular/polyfills-es2015.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>
<script type="module" type="text/javascript" src="angular/main-es2015.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>

<script nomodule type="text/javascript" src="angular/runtime-es5.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>
<script nomodule type="text/javascript" src="angular/polyfills-es5.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>
<script nomodule type="text/javascript" src="angular/main-es5.js?ver={{ config('assets.assets_version') }}"></script>
```

Why is the suspicious code included in the compiled files? Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this by playing around some more. I simply removed `type="text/javascript"` from the 3 scripts that were causing issues. I assume my browser was seeing two type definitions and therefore decided to download the scripts twice.

The suspicious code was a red herring and I now realise its purpose is to lazy-load different modules of our Angular project.